# XSLT testing using JUnit

Tags: xslt, junit

As part of my work , there will be many XSLT files.I am new to XSLT and learning.we planned to come up writing JUnit testcases for XSLT files. Is it possible to write JUnit testcases for the XSLT files?

Any Tips/Suggestions on how to proceed on this would be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

To achieve these kind of tests, the 3rd party [**xmlunit**](http://www.xmlunit.org/) framework might help you:

1. It extends the junit test cases, and provide some short-hand methods to avoid too much boilerplate code to transform your documents, and so on. You can also specify more easily a particular parser (e.g. Xerces, Saxon, ...) to perform your tests.
2. it provides you with some addtional **assertions** (e.g. `assertXMLEqual`, `assertXMLNotEqual`, ...) to check if an XML document (or a sub-part of it) matches a reference XML document, in the same way you check an integer equals another. It can also check some XPath expressions (`assertXpathExists`, `assertXpathEqual`, ...) or check if a document is valid (`assertXMLValid`) against a DTD.

It actually works quite like @flafoux has explained  in his answer, you will have to launch an XSL transformation on a sample input file, and check if the obtained result (or a sub-part of it, because sometimes there may be some contextual information needed only to run a transformation that you don't need to test) matches what is expected.

It is well explained on the website of the framework, the [javadoc](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/index.html) provides you with a sample test case which should fit your immediate requirements.  I found it easy to use, it should be the same for you, assuming you already know how to use jUnit.

Comment: Hi @potame, its interesting. This xmlunit framework works as JUnit to test the XML against the XSLT? Please explain me with some more information.is this a third party framework? how complex is it to use?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use different types of files :

- input file
- expected file
- XSLT file
- output file

Basically, you have to take *input* file A, then transform it applying *XSLT* file B, and check if *output* file C obtained is the same as the *expected* file D.
So you have to create manually input file, expected file and XSLT file are those you want to test.